# Ubuntu grub loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I try Ubuntu 18.04 via USB drive.

After installation of Ubuntu 18.04 in USB drive, now each time I start computer there is grub command line, and I am not sure what to type for open Ubuntu 18.04.

There is an easy way to select from where to load ubuntu? Maybe an UI?

I am not sure how I enter in my Ubuntu 16.04, but now I am afraid to shoutdown, since for a moment I think that I can't anymore enter on my Ubuntu 16.04 already installed...

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86532/discussion-on-question-by-zoroaster-ubuntu-grub-loader).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Boot Repair (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) I was able to fix issue. By running "Recommended repair" option. Important to do this without the usb drive plugged-in.

The grub menu choice will still be there, not sure how to remove it completely, but the main installation is first on list, so I can just hit enter to load it.

Thanks to @singrium for help